# Why does my First Function keep correcting other Function's edits

Tags: python, function, loops

I am trying to pre generate values in GenerateStats, and modify them in ModifyStats. But the End results of A or B is not modified.

```
def Final():

    GenerateStats()
    ModifyStats()

def GenerateStats():

    global A, B
    A = random.randint((-4), 4)
    B = random.randint((-4), 4)
    Total = A + B

    if (Total = 0)
        print A
        print B
    else:
        return GenerateStats()

def EditStats():

    global A, B
    X = random.randint(1, 2)
    if X = 1
       A = (A + 1)
    if X = 2
       B = (B + 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    Final()
```

End result is that the sum of A + B = 0, when it needs to be 1

A and B is information needed to be displayed at the end. Long Story short, its a character stat generator. A and B resemble stats like Athletics and Agility, determined in GenerateStats(). But the sum of the stats must be 0 before introducing any bonus from EditStats(), it randomizes which stat to upgrade(give a +1 bonus to) because you are given one free point to put anywhere.
Also I've been learning Python for less than a day so please bear with me :)

Comment: `if X = 1` is invalid syntax, as well as `if (Total = 0)`

Comment: What do you mean by "it keeps correcting the stats"?

Comment: Side note: have you considered to pass values as arguments and return them? All those global variables and your functions w/o return values make it hard to track what's happening.

Comment: Also, which part of this are you considering the "end result"?  Note that you don't do anything with `A` and `B` other than print them (before they have been modified!) in `GenerateStats`.

Comment: I'm assuming that `ModifyStats` and `EditStats` are supposed to be the same thing?  And if you want your initial `A`, `B` values to sum to zero - why in the world are you generating *two* random numbers?  Generate one, the second is necessarily the negative of the first.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you 0x5435!
You're right I was printing it before they were modified.I needed to
move the print into StatEdit() post modification to fixed it. So now

```
def Final():

    GenerateStats()
    ModifyStats()


def GenerateStats():

    global A, B
    A = random.randint((-4), 4)
    B = random.randint((-4), 4)
    Total = A + B

    while Total = 0
        break
    else:
        return GenerateStats()


def EditStats():

    global A, B
    X = random.randint(1, 2)
    if X = 1
       A = (A + 1)
    if X = 2
       B = (B + 1)

    print A
    print B

if __name__ == '__main__':

    Final()
```

This properly Generated the Stats while the modifications properly put in its random place.